# How android swipe event reflected in View?

Tags: android, input

Such as touch the screen and move or use "input swipe" in adb shell, how android system decide to scroll or not and the distance to scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer.  Gesture detection.  Scrolling views like ScrollView, ListView and RecyclerView will register to receive onTouchEvent events from the screen.  They will then track those events over time to detect things like swipes, including the direction, velocity and acceleration of the swipe.

From there, they can make a decision on whether to scroll, how far to scroll, and in what direction.  Each view will do this differently based on how their content is laid out, whether there is additional content that be scrolled to, etc..

In particular ScrollView uses a VelocityTracker to track the series of touch events, and uses that to calculate what to do.  There's other options (like the GestureDetector class) available to do simple gesture detection in custom views.

Do yourself a favor, and look at the source code for ScrollView in your IDE.
In particular the onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent methods.